# Creating a bar plot in python

Tags: python

I'm working on my school project which asks me to create a bar plot. I'm unable to understand the function, can anyone please help?

```
def get_barplot(f_dict,title):
    """
    *******  CHANGE 2 (50 points) **********
    Shows and saves the Bar Plot
    """
    #Uncomment and fill the blanks
    freq_df = pd.DataFrame(f_dict._______,columns=['key','value']) #coverts the dictionary as dataframe
    bar_plot = ___.barplot(_________________________)
    bar_plot.set(title=title+'_BarPlot',xlabel='Words', ylabel='Count') #Setting title and labels
    plt.xticks(rotation=45) #Rotating the each word beacuse of the length of the words
    plt.show()
    bar_plot.figure.savefig(title+'_barplot.png',bbox_inches='tight') #saving the file
```

This is the code. Can anyone please let me know what should i write in the blanks given? I've spent the last hour trying to understand but I can't

I tried to use different methods but it didnt work.

Comment: share  your `f_dict` format..

Answer (score 0):

It is always useful to look at the API documentation when trying to understand the library functions.

**Blank 1**: In the first line of your code you are trying to create a Pandas data frame from a dictionary.  The first argument for `pd.DataFrame` is the `data` (see [pandas.DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html)). In this case, the items in your dictionary i.e. `f_dict.items()`. The `columns` parameter provides you a clue here as these are `"key"` and `"value"` i.e. an item in the dictionary.

**Blanks 2 and 3**: I assume you are using Seaborn which has a `.barplot` method (see [seaborn.barplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html)).  I also assume that this has been imported with the alias `sns`. Seaborn's `.barplot` method takes a data frame as the first argument which in this case would be the data frame you created in the first line of your code i.e. `sns.barplot(data=freq_df)`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you must pass to the dataframe method not just a dictionary, but its items:

```
freq_df = pd.DataFrame(f_dict.items(),columns=['key','value'])
```

Next, you need to create a barplot. Pandas has a slightly different method for creating a barplot (.plot.bar()), in your case you use .barplot, which corresponds to the method from the seaborn library.
As I understand it, you need to build a barplot for the frequency of values. The following code does this:

```
bar_plot = sns.barplot(x = 'value', y = freq_df['value'].value_counts(), data = freq_df)
```

And make sure you import the seaborn library. The abbreviation sns is usually used for it:

```
import seaborn as sns
```